# How to Validate Dynamically Added Input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've the problem with div id in script. I just want to know how to control div id for using function id in another script. Here's my form:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 field_wrapper">
            <div data-role="dynamic-fields">
                <div class="form-inline">                                                   
                    <div class="form-group" id="txtboxToFilter">
                        <label for="nip">NIP:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="UserName" onkeyup="checkname();" placeholder="Masukkan NIP" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button btn btn-success btn-xs" title="Tambah Pegawai"><i class='fa fa-fw fa-plus'></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <span id="name_status"></span>
                </div> 
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>
```

And here's my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div data-role="dynamic-fields"><div class="form-inline"><div class="form-group" id="txtboxToFilter"><label for="nip">NIP:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="UserName" onkeyup="checkname();" placeholder="Masukkan NIP" required/></div><div class="form-group"><label for="jabatan">Jabatan:</label><select class="form-control" id="jabatan" name="jeniskejadian" required><option value=""></option><option value="SMC / KAKANSAR">SMC / KAKANSAR</option><option value="STAFF OPERASI / KASIOPS">STAFF OPERASI / KASIOPS</option><option value="OSC / KORPOS">OSC / KORPOS</option><option value="DANTIM">DANTIM</option><option value="RESCUER">RESCUER</option><option value="STAFF KOMUNIKASI">STAFF KOMUNIKASI</option><option value="HUMAS">HUMAS</option><option value="STAFF ADMINLOG">STAFF ADMINLOG</option></select></div><div class="form-group"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Hapus Pegawai"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-minus"></i></a></div><span id="name_status"></span></div></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        x++; //Increment field counter
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});

function checkname()
{
 var name=document.getElementById( "UserName" ).value;

 if(name)
 {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'checkdata.php',
  data: {
   user_name:name,
  },
  success: function (response) {
   $( '#name_status' ).html(response);
   if(response=="OK")   
   {
    return true;    
   }
   else
   {
    return false;   
   }
  }
  });
 }
 else
 {
  $( '#name_status' ).html("");
  return false;
 }
}
```

For the first time in

```
<div class="form-group" id="txtboxToFilter">
    <label for="nip">NIP:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="UserName" onkeyup="checkname();" placeholder="Masukkan NIP" required/>
</div>
```

It can be used to using function checkname(), but if I would to click in

```
<div class="form-group">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button btn btn-success btn-xs" title="Tambah Pegawai"><i class='fa fa-fw fa-plus'></i></a>
</div>
```

for adding the same input type text with function of my script $(addButton)

```
var fieldHTML = '<div data-role="dynamic-fields"><div class="form-inline"><div class="form-group" id="txtboxToFilter"><label for="nip">NIP:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="UserName" onkeyup="checkname();" placeholder="Masukkan NIP" required/></div><div class="form-group"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Hapus Pegawai"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-minus"></i></a></div><span id="name_status"></span></div></div>';
```

but the result is that var fieldHTML couldn't use function onkeyup checkname(). Please help me...

Comment: So you want to get the reference to the `div` on every `keyup` event??

Comment: Yes. I want my fieldHTML can use function onkeyup="checkname()".

Comment: You are getting the same output on `keyup` for every new `fieldHTML` created, Right??

Comment: Yeah. I want function of checkname() can be used when fieldHTML is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a reference of the element on which the inline event listener is attached to. You need to pass the this reference to the function and use the `this` reference to get the element.

Change you functions by adding `this`.

e.g.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="UserName" onkeyup="checkname(this);" placeholder="Masukkan NIP" required/>
```

Also, for fieldHTML

```
var fieldHTML = '<div data-role="dynamic-fields"><div class="form-inline"><div class="form-group" id="txtboxToFilter"><label for="nip">NIP:</label> 
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="UserName" onkeyup="checkname(this);" placeholder="Masukkan NIP" required/></div><div class="form-group"><label for="jabatan">Jabatan:</label><select class="form-control" id="jabatan" name="jeniskejadian" required><option value=""></option><option value="SMC / KAKANSAR">SMC / KAKANSAR</option><option value="STAFF OPERASI / KASIOPS">STAFF OPERASI / KASIOPS</option><option value="OSC / KORPOS">OSC / KORPOS</option><option value="DANTIM">DANTIM</option><option value="RESCUER">RESCUER</option><option value="STAFF KOMUNIKASI">STAFF KOMUNIKASI</option><option value="HUMAS">HUMAS</option><option value="STAFF ADMINLOG">STAFF ADMINLOG</option></select></div><div class="form-group"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Hapus Pegawai"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-minus"></i></a></div><span id="name_status"></span></div></div>';
```

Function checkname(element) as :

variable `element` contains the element this is being used. You can access the element by using `element` variable.

```
 function checkname(element)
 {
      var name= element.value;

      console.log('Checkname '+name);
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the function of console.log('Checkname '+name); ? I'm beginner in programming :(

Comment: @DikaAndharu `console.log` prints the output in the console log on the browser. Open chrome or firefox. Right click and then open `inspect element`. Then go to console tab. You will see the output there. It is better than using `alert`

Comment: Sorry, It works but the result of selecting from database was not successful. When the result is "OK" that just printing to the first input type text <span id="name_status"></span>. And <span id="name_status"></span> of fieldHTML couldn't work...

Comment: @DikaAndharu What is the returned `response` ??

Comment: The response is just returned for the first <span id="name_status"></span>. When I tried to inserting in input type text from fieldHTML, the result is just showing in the first <span id="name_status"></span>. Could you please look at my span id on input type text original and fieldHTML. Is it possible sir ? If that's impossible, It's okay..

Comment: @DikaAndharu You cannot have same `id` for all the elements. `id` is always unique.

Comment: Omg I forgot with that. Yeah id is always unique. Thank you for your help. :)